# Local variable addressing in Ghidra

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ghidra

I've been trying to solve a crackme challenge by examining it's decompiled version by Ghidra.
So I figured the code where the `strcmp` is done as shown in the figure below. Now I need to to patch the program to make it print the password if `strcmp` fails.

- The password is stored in `local_40`

But I don't know how to patch the instruction to print out the value at local_40

Instead of `MOV dword ptr [ESP],0x4b1050` what variable in this instruction should be edited? If my understanding is correct then the above instruction is loading the ESP register with the value at `0x4b1050`
so how will I get the address of `local_40`?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text, copy the text into the post directly.

Comment: @EOF Images of what text?

Comment: `local_40` seems to be at `ebp-0x3c`. You should be able to fit `lea eax, [ebp-0x3c] / mov DWORD [esp], eax` in place of the `mov`.

Comment: a much easier solution would be to pactch `JNZ` to `JZ` at `0x401508` :)